# PHP function to print how many times a function is called

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function that counts how many times it has been called

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function print_calls() {
    count(print_calls);
}

print_calls();

?>
```

I want it to display how many times the function is called like

```
print_calls(); // 1
print_calls(); // 2
print_calls(); // 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php

function callCount(){
static $calls=0;
echo $calls++;
}

callCount();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable for this:

```
function print_calls() {
  static $callCount=0;
  printf("%d\n", ++$callCount);
}
```

Note that this only keeps the counts for the current process, so if you use this in a web server the count will be reset for each page you access. If you need persistent counts, you would have to write it to a file or use a `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: He asks "I am trying to make a function", not "I am trying to count for all functions". From the question it's not really clear if he wants this for just one function or for profiling.

Comment: You want `printf`, not `print`

Comment: sorry about the typo, see @iainn's comment

Answer (score 0):

Global variables may be dangerous. Be carefoul.

You can define a variable as counter and a function that uses that external variable.

```
php > $counter = 0;
php > function ciao() { global $counter; $counter++; echo $counter; }
```

From now, ... each time you call that function it print the variable incremented. This happens because the scope of `$counter` is not local to the function but global to the file.

```
php > ciao();
1
php > ciao();
2
php > ciao();
3
php > ciao();
4
php > ciao();
5
```